# How to dynamically type arguments between different methods in a map

Tags: typescript

I'm having trouble dynamically mapping expected arguments of a function to the function selected in a parent wrapper. I've managed to correctly map all possible methods that *could* be called, but Typescript is throwing errors at the arguments that I pass.

Here is what I have:

```
type TGenerateSetA = { city: number; address: number; }
const setASelects = {
  city: ({ appendComma }: { appendComma: boolean }) => `city${appendComma ? ',' : ''}`,
  address: ({ appendComma }: { appendComma: boolean }) => `address${appendComma ? ',' : ''}`,
};

type TGenerateSetB = { user: number; role: number; }
const setBSelects = {
  user: ({ appendComma }: { appendComma: boolean }) => `user${appendComma ? ',' : ''}`,
  role: ({ appendComma }: { appendComma: boolean }) => `role${appendComma ? ',' : ''}`,
};

type TSetObject = Record<string, ({ appendComma }: { appendComma: boolean }) => string>;
interface ISetMapping {
    SET_A: TSetObject
    SET_B: TSetObject
}

const SELECTS: ISetMapping = {
  SET_A: setASelects,
  SET_B: setBSelects,
}

type TGenerateCommonResult = {
  selectFrom: keyof ISetMapping;
} & TGenerateSetA
const generateCommonResult = ({ selectFrom, ...args }: TGenerateCommonResult) => {
  const result: string[] = [];

  const totalEnabledSelects = Object.values(args).reduce((acc, shouldSelect) => acc + shouldSelect, 0);
  let selectsAdded = 0;

  

    Object.entries(args).forEach(([select, shouldSelect], index, self) => {
        if (shouldSelect) {
            result.push(SELECTS[selectFrom][select]({appendComma: selectsAdded + 1 !== totalEnabledSelects}));
        }

    selectsAdded++;
    });

    return result.join(' ');
}

console.log(generateCommonResult({ selectFrom: 'SET_A', city: 1, address: 0 })); // no error expected
console.log(generateCommonResult({ selectFrom: 'SET_B', user: 1, city: 0 })); // error expected
console.log(generateCommonResult({ selectFrom: 'SET_B', user: 1, role: 0 })); // no error expected
```

How can I get this to work?

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKg4hAdhATgQ2BAyhYBBKAXigG8oBjAS1AC4pEBXAWwCNUBuKNAE25QgDOAuo1YcoAXwBQ5APaIBwKANx4cAGwjlgAoqSlQK1EHQAUZNGEiJuAYVlMmaSXQtWkdh07otZszWiIkgCURAB8UAAGVKAAJCSW1p6OzgD8UADkADQZUHQZGRKRWQZcvPxCZm5J9ikupFzuNrXeUL7+EIEh4VE8fIIC8YkeLWmZOXmZhcVSEuxSUqCQsAjI6Jg4wABCemQMKigizGwonCgdR2KnkjLyisq4WxpaOrul+6hVjTVezhKu3xGvx8fgCQQkoUIEUiHxQQyayScUHS2Vy+WmJUM500X2GzV+9WqQJSII6XQhPUi2Ig8J+dRRE3RRRKcwWS2gME2AHkWAArF56ABKWlkKG4AB5FChKIgAOZZKDmQH4ur-Bp4xFoUlg7pQ5TAaVysLzGWYFAAMzQ5GgAElNgBZRIy2X6ACQWAAojAAPp4Oic3A8-naKTur3erb+7l8l6zBZyBRKT0AGQ9tk5dDtuEdVmdb0Mnp9foe+Ge2gEmKghYjdBU2zLOhZbPAHNWqAwEBa8mFAgY6iUxBIpRUmm0ADFzkw6ABrCAgWTmqBZ4A5sDO+YSKAAMhWSHbG1Ut0TUFle-Wna83cEfYHirII5eE4cCoAdG+0ChZbo1fAzx2u4gPY3pCERDoYCb3BUN61gazoANoALp6Ih8ylBBSjALIwBoOoHqIGgLCaNwDa6MQQYvC+ABuOEMIIpgfl+wQvvw3AMNapj0eQ5AKgIAAWsh9sRECjsAIFcFxUAANTKPxgkNgqAAMwTzIYmhKA+5Z4LwEDcHoCmoYYCyuuR2gvkgsF0QxAhMeaooelavEcXBGnADxsnqEJIkIQqMrcBAAAePHCeaYlDq6rqUIuph8QJHkNqEYXhVB-YvmA+yOSmaacs5wmPpOCE5V55gaqMta5Zp2m6dJACMUAAISEMQmHYbh+GETpJEQspoautIpSGC5AhaX53CSZJ8y9d1ob8MADAoEEyXAC+vKyDKpi5Bk3V9RBHQvuosiyqYp5rP+l6Ade-ZKi5T5Tpk1Z4NkRi0FA1UKn0FTCFACkhMpUAAPR-fQshQKg5woCD-mQNoOlHgIu37Ydx37hejhXr2l33uVwA3fk1ZbI9sJ0K9T0mF9P2cADIMoGDENQ5g3Cw-DB1HX+mAAUBGMPCJON3eG+MKoTL0KtSdDfV1FOA4gwOg6KtMvDpQA)

Comment: Correct, `& TGenerateSetA` would work if `TGenerateSetA` arguments are always to be passed, however, I need this to be dynamic, as `TGenerateSetB` or (even `TGenerateSetC` down the line) are to be passed instead. [Here's an updated](https://tsplay.dev/wXOA8W) link that provides a little more context, I hope

Comment: Maybe [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/m3xLLW) would work for you?  I don't see anywhere you've codified the relationship between the keys and values; your `ISetMapping` type doesn't distinguish between `TGenerateSetA` and `TGenerateSetB`.  So somewhere you'll need a type of the form `{SET_A: TGenerateSetA; SET_B: TGenerateSetB, ...}` to map over.

Comment: Yup.. that did it. It seems a bit messy, but it gets the job done, wow, thank you. Maybe you can submit it as a comment, so I could accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want `TGenerateCommonResult` to be a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) type, with `selectFrom` as the *discriminant* property.  You could write that type out directly if you want:

```
interface TGenerateCommonResultA extends TGenerateSetA {
  selectFrom: "SET_A"
}
interface TGenerateCommonResultB extends TGenerateSetB {
  selectFrom: "SET_B"
}
type TGenerateCommonResult =
  TGenerateCommonResultA | TGenerateCommonResultB;
```

And this would work as desired:

```
generateCommonResult({ selectFrom: 'SET_A', city: 1, address: 0 }); //okay
generateCommonResult({ selectFrom: 'SET_B', user: 1, city: 0 }); // error
generateCommonResult({ selectFrom: "SET_B", role: 1, user: 2 }); // okay
generateCommonResult({ selectFrom: "SET_A", role: 1, user: 2 }); // error
```

---

If you have a lot of those then you might want to have the `TGenerateCommonResult` computed programmatically from some mapping interface which just relates each key to the corresponding value:

```
interface GenerateCommonResultMapping {
  SET_A: TGenerateSetA,
  SET_B: TGenerateSetB
}
```

That interface or something with the same information should ideally already exist in your code base.  The example you provided doesn't do this; the closest is `ISetMapping`, but the value types of that interface don't distinguish between `TGenerateSetA` and `TGenerateSetB` or indeed care about that type at all.  I'm not going to worry about that here, but presumably you'd want to refactor your code so as to preserve and use that information.

Anyway, given that mapping we can compute `TGenerateCommonResult` as a *distributive object type* (a term coined in [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109)), which is a a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) into which we immediately [index](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) with the full keyset to get a union.  Essentially if you have a type function `F<K>` where `K` is a keylike type and you want to distribute `F` over unions in `K`, you can write `{[P in K]: F<P>}[K]`, which turns `K1 | K2 | ... | KN` into `F<K1> | F<K2> | ... | F<KN>`.  In your case the type function is the intersection of `{ selectFrom: K }` and `GenerateCommonResultMapping[K]`.  So the type we want is

```
type TGenerateCommonResult = { [K in keyof GenerateCommonResultMapping]:
  { selectFrom: K } & GenerateCommonResultMapping[K]
}[keyof GenerateCommonResultMapping]
```

You can verify that it evaluates to

```
/* type TGenerateCommonResult = 
 ({ selectFrom: "SET_A"; } & TGenerateSetA) | 
 ({ selectFrom: "SET_B"; } & TGenerateSetB) 
*/
```

which is structurally identical to the version written out manually above.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKg4hAdhATgQ2BAyhYBBKAXigG8oBjAS1AC4pEBXAWwCNUBuKNAE25QgDOAuo1YcoAXwBQ5APaIBwKANx4cAGwjlgAoqSlQK1EHQAUZNGEiJuAYVlMmaSXQtWkdh07otZszWiIkgCURAB8UAAGVKAAJCSW1p6OzgD8UADkADQZUHQZGRKRWQZcvPxCZm5J9ikupFzuNrXeUL7+EIEh4VE8fIIC8YkeLWmZOXmZhcVSEuxSUqCQsAjI6Jg4wABCemQMKigizGwonCgdR2KnkjLyisq4WxpaOrul+6hVjTVezhKu3xGvx8fgCQQkoUIEUiHxQQyayScUHS2Vy+WmJUM500X2GzV+9WqQJSII6XQhPUi2Ig8J+dRRE3RRRKcwWS2gME2AHkWAArF56ABKWlkKG4AB5FChKIgAOZZKDmQH4ur-Bp4xFoUlg7pQ5TAaVysLzGWYFAAMzQ5GgAElNgBZRIy2X6QxYACiMAA+ng6JzcDz+dpSh7vVs-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-DcAw1qmHd5DkAqAgABayCOR0tdoo1cJ9UAANTKH9AN1gqAAMwTzIYmhKNFOh4LwEDcHocMrVAZ3aO1SBzbd90CI95qiu6Vo-e9Ylo990PqIDn46QqMrcJO33ZeaIPjYYlDKaYv3-czdahPzhhTT57VgPstNJimnL00DX6bjpKus0qGqjIWqsCBjnPY5DACMUAAISEMQG1bTte0HVjx0hIjpSGNIrsri8BuY9w4Pg0jIR4-wwAMCgQTTaO7W8rIMqmLkGQu+7NUwXVDWjs1OWxZke7ZEYtBQCbCp9BUwhQHDgdQI2jayLJaAgFIyehRRPkZ61P7Z-mWy57CdCF3nJhlxXVfjig5woA3tVhTercxe3u6d9uCrUr3Co91AABMQ+NlANd1xPKdT+nWWZ3Pe6L1NFwF6vBx0JvEKcMPqBj0AA)